# How do I bypass the typing of `GO` in `sqlcmd`?

Tags: linux, client, sql-server-2017

sqlcmd has this most annoying this of having to type `GO` after every command, how can I get around this?

```
SELECT 1 AS "foo"
2> GO
foo        
-----------
          1
(1 rows affected)
```

Can I make this like psql...

```
test=# SELECT 1;
 ?column? 
----------
        1
(1 row)
```

Comment: Maybe use a different SQL client?

Comment: i am not sure if [-c command line option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility) for sqlcmd can help here... as far as I know sqlcmd does not work with out a batch terminator. But maybe a semicolon will do the job there

Comment: Just add a simple `;` after your query and you're good to go. (e.g. `SELECT 1 AS 'foo';`

Answer (score 2):

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility

With `-q` you can execute multiple query, as you do not get your prompt back until you hit `ctrl+c`.

> -q" cmdline query " Executes a query when sqlcmd starts, but does not exit sqlcmd when the query has finished running.
>   Multiple-semicolon-delimited queries can be executed. Use quotation
>   marks around the query, as shown in the following example.

This is in my workstation.

[image: If you want to exit use <code>-Q</code> instead] of `-q`.

> -Q" cmdline query " Executes a query when sqlcmd starts and then immediately exits sqlcmd. Multiple-semicolon-delimited queries can be
>   executed. Use quotation marks around the query, as shown in the
>   following example.[image]